# NodeJs middleware that supports both Koa & Express

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I'm trying to write a middleware that supports both Koa & Express.
The middleware is designed to be an external package, which will be used by service like so:

```
myMiddleware(app);
```

Where 'app' can be either Koa or Express.
During the middleware initalization, I set a property in 'app', like so:

```
    app.context.parsedSwagger = parsedSwagger;
```

If I use Koa with (ctx, next) I'm able to access it just fine.
But when I use koa-connect, I don't see it in the 'req' object.

Please advise.

Comment: did you tried [koa-connect](https://github.com/vkurchatkin/koa-connect) ?

Comment: was not aware of it, taking a look, thank you.

Comment: @HamzaFatmi, It almost fits, I've updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: when you use koa-connect , your express middleware will use the `ctx`, it will be like any other koa middleware, you can acess the request object with `ctx.request`.